# O(n*log(n)) Turing Machine with exactly 1 tape for "equal number of a's and b's in a given word"?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, turing-machines

I need to build a TM  with exactly 1 tape for the language L = {w| w is a word with same number of a's and b's in it, for example: abba, aababb}

The TM has to have ONLY 1 tape and it has to run in O(n*log(n)) time. I understand how to do it in O(n^2) but i have no idea how to make it n*log(n).

If i have the input w = "aaaa....abbbbb....bb" for example, where w = a ^ n/2  * b ^n/2 (which is the worst case) then i will go backwards each time (to delete each a for each b) and the steps taken will be of size 1,2,3,4.....n. Sum(1 to n) is  O(n^2)...

Help ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

At a high level, the solution I'm thinking of processes the word in order from left to right. At all times, there is a prefix of the word that has been processed, and a suffix of the word that has not been processed. Letting `delta` be the number of `a`s in the prefix minus the number of `b`s, the tape looks like this at the beginning of each iteration:

```
<big-endian abs(delta)><sign(delta)><suffix>
                                    ^
                                tape head
```

To process the next letter (i.e., the first letter in the suffix), add/subtract one from `delta` depending on the whether the letter is an `a` or `b` and whether sign is `+` or `-`, moving the representation of `delta` one space to the right in the process. At the end, check whether `delta` is zero.

It might be easier to use a two's complement representation where the leftmost digit is presumed to repeat infinitely, but I'm not sure if there are any hidden snags.

Comment: This is a surprisingly simple solution! It's pretty much how you would write the code on a regular computer except for the part about moving the counter up through memory.